# Feasiblity of a long spinning top using an electromagnet to pull on Earth's magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, rotation, drag

Would it be feasible to build a infinitely spinning top (ref. Inception) by including a battery powered electromagnet who's polarity flipped in sync with the top's rotation such that the pull against the Earth's magnetic field countered energy losses to air resistance, friction, etc.

For scale, lets consider only a toy sized top sized to fit in the palm of 1 hand, powered by a between 1 and 3 CR2 3-volt batteries.

Also, lets not go crazy and start talking vacuums and mag-lev. Desktop environment, maybe needle point on a steel surface.

To be clear here, I'm looking for an "are the orders of magnitude of the forces in play feasible" style answer here. Unless someone wants to really dork out and do the math on air resistance.